# Tomcat memory clean without restarting the server

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, memory-leaks, tomcat7

I am using Tomcat 7.0.50 server.

How can I delete the tomcat cache memory without restarting the server?

Comment: Please remove the bold style.

Comment: What *exactly* are you thinking of when you say "tomcat cache memory"?

Comment: while i am un deploying war files from tomcat, i saw still some classes are loaded in memory. i need to delete those classes,without restarting the server .so how can i clean this memory..

Comment: Are you in production environment? what is your java error : outofmemory? Is a classical error when you deploy several apps in the same tomcat without restart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find how to delete Tomcat Cache [here](http://support.grouplink.net/ehelpdesk/kb/kbView.glml;jsessionid=3859FD08443F5421FDE110C70FB53053?kbId=161)

You can delete the "work" folder under Tomcat Home. Even if it does allow you to delete the folder while tomcat is running, I would guess it will cause troubles to your running site.

Answer (score 0):

If your Tomcat installation is configured to have a ROOT directory for your webapp, you will have to find a path like

```
/tomcat/base-myapplication/webapps/ROOT/
```

which contains your deployed webapp.

Just delete everything inside, including sub directories META-INF, WEB-INF, VAADIN etc., and then re-deploy your webapp. This worked for me even with tomcat running, but it doesn't hurt to restart tomcat after deployment.